# pthread_cond_broadcast not signalling threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

I'm really struggling with understanding how to lock and unlock mutexes in a way that lets threads run at the same time. Right now I'm trying to have every thread do something, then wait until all threads are ready, and then repeat it. This should happen repeatedly, so I have it all in a conditioned loop. My problem is, it seems like my broadcast is never received by any threads, as every thread that waits for the signal waits forever, while the thread that sent the signal continues.

I've dumbed my code down to make it as simple as possible while still being compileable and runnable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define num_threads 4

int repeat = 1;
int timesLooped = 0;
int waitingThreads = 0;
int threadNo = -1;
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
pthread_cond_t condition;


//thread body
void* threadBody(void* arg){

   
   //sensitive info: requires lock
   if(pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1)){ printf("error1\n"); }
     threadNo++;
     int threadId = threadNo;
     //other info is set here as well in my code
   if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1)){ printf("error2\n"); }

   //main loop in the thread body
   while(repeat == 1){

      if(pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1)){ printf("error3\n"); }

      //wait until all threads are ready
      while(waitingThreads < num_threads - 1){

         printf(" %d! ", threadId);
         waitingThreads++;
         pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex1);

         printf(" %d ", threadId);
         if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1)){ printf("error4\n"); }

      }
  
      //last thread will broadcast
      if(waitingThreads == num_threads - 1){

         printf("\n\nthread %d was last! broadcasting to let everyone proceed...", threadId);
         timesLooped++;
         waitingThreads = 0;
        if(timesLooped == 3){
            repeat = 0;
         }
sleep(1);
         pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
         if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1)){ printf("error5\n"); }
         

 


      }



   }
printf("\n\nexiting thread %d\n", threadId);
   pthread_exit((void*) arg);
}





int main(int argc, char** argv){

   pthread_t threads[num_threads];
   void* retval;

   //create threads
   for(long i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadBody, (void*) i);
   }

   //join threads
   for(long j = 0; j < num_threads; j++){
      pthread_join(threads[j], &retval);
   }


printf("\n\nDONE\n");
}
```

This gives me an output of:

> thread 3 was last! broadcasting to let everyone proceed...
>
> thread 2 was last! broadcasting to let everyone proceed...
>
> thread 1 was last! broadcasting to let everyone proceed...
>
> exiting thread 1   (deadlock, other threads never exit)

Comment: You would get better answers if you provide actual compilable test (the code you provided is not valid and can't be compiled). Bonus points for not double-spacing it.

Comment: I've updated my code to be compilable.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two bugs in your program.

1. You have a data race (see this [blog post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong)).

   When threads `0` through `num_threads - 1` access `waitingThreads` in `if (waitingThreads == num_threads - 1) ...`, they do so outside of the lock (i.e. they race).
2. You don't allow threads other than the last one to run (this is your primary question).

   `pthread_cond_wait` returns when *both* condition has been signaled *and* the mutex can be re-acquired.

   But your last thread *immediately* re-acquires the mutex upon releasing it, so no other thread can proceed.

   I expect that if you add `sleep` or `usleep` after `pthread_mutex_unlock` in the last thread, your program will start working as you expect it to.

Comment: I've tried having my last thread sleep for a bit, but it doesn't affect the output. And for the mutex lock suggestion... I lock my mutex at the top of my repeating loop, so I don't see how the threads would access that outside of the lock.

Comment: I fixed one of my main problems. I had been incrementing threadNo and then only referencing that, so eventually it was always 3. I set a new variable for printing purposes. I've gotten my code to the point that ONE thread can exit, but the others don't.

Comment: @Lazarus You haven't fixed any of the data races (actually you added more). Also, you added `sleep` *before* `pthread_mutex_unlock`, which is useless.